# How to display a CSV file string as HTML with line-break tags?

Tags: java, html, regex, string, jsp

I have a CSV file stored in my database as a blob.

My API only allows me to return it as a single String - I would have preferred a `List` of `Strings` representing each line of the file.

```
String fileText = new String(blobDb.fetchData(key, 0, fileLength));
```

Rather than display the file as an unending block of text:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Contents:</title>
</head>
<body>

${fileText}

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to somehow break it up into separate lines of HTML broken up by `<br/>` tags?

Comment: Does the blob maintain any newlines in the CSV file?

Comment: Just don't forget to escape the `filetext` content.

Answer (score 3):

Either use the HTML `<pre>` element

```xml
<pre>${fileText}</pre>
```

*or* apply CSS `white-space: pre;` on the containing element

```xml
<div style="white-space: pre;">${fileText}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fileText = fileText.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
```